# Does ki leech and ki focus bow require a swift action to activate, or are they like ki strike?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, monk, archetype

I am playing a [Qinggong](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/core-classes/monk/archetypes/paizo---monk-archetypes/qinggong-monk)/[Zen Archer](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/core-classes/monk/archetypes/paizo---monk-archetypes/zen-archer) Monk and I have a question about the ki abilities that they can gain. The ones in question are [ki leech](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/k/ki-leech) and [ki focus bow](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/core-classes/monk/archetypes/paizo---monk-archetypes/qinggong-monk).

I asked because both have similar wording to the [monk](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/core-classes/monk)'s [ki fist](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/core-classes/monk#TOC-Ki-Pool-Su-).

> At 4th level, a monk gains a pool of ki points, supernatural energy he can use to accomplish amazing feats. The number of points in a monk's ki pool is equal to 1/2 his monk level + his Wisdom modifier. As long as he has at least 1 point in his ki pool, he can make a ki strike.

Ki leech costs 0 ki points to use and has similar wording

> You place your spirit in a receptive state so when you confirm a critical hit against a living enemy or reduce a living enemy to 0 or fewer hit points, you can steal some of that creature’s ki. This replenishes 1 point of ki as long as you have at least 1 ki point in your ki pool. This does not allow you to exceed your ki pool’s maximum. This ability does not stack with similar abilities (such as the steal ki ability of the hungry ghost monk). This spell has no effect if you do not have a ki pool.

Same with Ki Focus bow

> At 17th level, as long as he has at least 1 point of ki in his ki pool, a zen archer may treat arrows fired from his bow as if they were ki focus weapons, allowing him to use his special ki attacks as if his arrows were unarmed attacks.

So my question comes down to this. Since for the ki strike you do not spend a swift (or any other kind) of action to use, as long as you have one point its active, does this also apply to these other two abilities since the wording is the same?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In short for Ki Leach take a Standard Action but for Ki Focus Bow Yes no action is needed for the long answer see the following:

For Ki Leach since it is a spell the Qinggong Monk Archetype treats it as a spell like ability

> Spells: These ki powers duplicate the effects of a spell, and are spell-like abilities. A qinggong monk's class level is the caster level for these spell-like abilities, and she uses Wisdom to determine her concentration check bonus. [Qinggong Monk (Archetype)](http://paizo.com/pathfinderRPG/prd/ultimateMagic/spellcastingClassOptions/monk.html#qinggong-monk-(archetype))

and Spell-like Abilities unless specifically noted otherwise have a standard action casting time

> A spell-like ability usually has a limit on how often it can be used. A constant spell-like ability or one that can be used at will has no use limit; unless otherwise stated, a creature can only use a constant spell-like ability on itself. Reactivating a constant spell-like ability is a swift action. **Using all other spell-like abilities is a standard action unless noted otherwise, and doing so provokes attacks of opportunity.** It is possible to make a concentration check to use a spell-like ability defensively and avoid provoking an attack of opportunity, just as when casting a spell. A spell-like ability can be disrupted just as a spell can be. Spell-like abilities cannot be used to counterspell, nor can they be counterspelled. [Spell-Like Abilities (Sp)](http://paizo.com/pathfinderRPG/prd/monsters/universalMonsterRules.html#spell-like-abilities)

Emphasis Mine

For the Zen Archer it is much easier as the Zen Archer Archetype treats the Ki Focus Bow as a Supernatural ability

> **Ki Focus Bow (Su):** At 17th level, as long as he has at least 1 point of ki in his ki pool, a zen archer may treat arrows fired from his bow as if they were ki focus weapons, allowing him to use his special ki attacks as if his arrows were unarmed attacks. This ability replaces tongue of the sun and moon. [Ki Focus Bow](http://paizo.com/pathfinderRPG/prd/advancedPlayersGuide/coreClasses/monk.html#ki-focus-bow)

and Supernatural Abilities are defined as

> **Supernatural Abilities (Su):** Supernatural abilities are magical attacks, defenses, and qualities. These abilities can be always active or they can require a specific action to utilize. The supernatural ability's description includes information on how it is used and its effects. [Supernatural Abilities](http://paizo.com/pathfinderRPG/prd/coreRulebook/gettingStarted.html#supernatural-abilities)

Thus the Ki Focus Bow ability is active as long as your Ki pool has at least 1 point remaining.